# Cannot create a virtual host for local ip address

Tags: networking, server, virtualhost

I am running a GitLab instance on my local machine in `http://127.0.0.1:180/` IP address. However, I would like to access to Gitlab by `gitlab.local`. To do so, I edited the `/etc/hosts` file as follows

```
127.0.0.1:180 gitlab.local
```

and restarted the network by

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

But `http://gitlab.local/` still gives me `This site can’t be reached` error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the port number in `/etc/hosts`. Try this instead:

```
127.0.0.1 gitlab.local
```

Comment: Then I have to browse `http://gitlab.local:180/`.

Comment: Yes, forwarding connections from one port to another is not something you can do with `/etc/hosts`. iptables can do that - something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993249/113848